# Join query in Django ORM with multiple joins against same table

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need multiple joins against same table.
My Models:

```
class Goods(models.Model):
     art = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class PriceGroups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Price(models.Model):
   price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
   goods = models.ForeignKey(Goods, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
   pricegroup = models.ForeignKey(PriceGroups, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The table Price like:

| Goods_id | PriceGroups_id | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 2 | 25 |
| 1 | 3 | 30 |
| 2 | 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 2 | 45 |
| 2 | 3 | 50 |

I need result like:

| Goods_id | PriceGroups_id_1_price | PriceGroups_id_2_price | PriceGroups_id_3_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 25 | 30 |
| 2 | 40 | 45 | 50 |

This SQL works:

```
    SELECT goods.id, PriceGroups_id_1.price, riceGroups_id_2.price, 
    PriceGroups_id_3.price
    FROM price_goods AS goods 
    LEFT JOIN price_price AS PriceGroups_id_1 ON goods.id = PriceGroups_id_1.goods_id
    LEFT JOIN price_price AS PriceGroups_id_2 ON goods.id = PriceGroups_id_2.goods_id
    LEFT JOIN price_price AS PriceGroups_id_3 ON goods.id = PriceGroups_id_3.goods_id
    WHERE PriceGroups_id_1.pricegroup_id = 1
    AND PriceGroups_id_2.pricegroup_id = 2
    AND PriceGroups_id_3.pricegroup_id = 3
    '''
```

For one pricegroup_id work:

```
Goods.objects.filter(price__pricegroup_id = 1).annotate(PriceGroups_id_1 = F('price__price'))
```

No idea how to do in Django ORM....any way to do this?

Comment: Explain *what* you want to do, not *how* you want to do.

Comment: I manage to make a dictionary like in the top table.

Comment: You can use ```.raw``` to write the complex SQL query itself without using the django ORM. I am telling you this because i have seen limitations in django ORM while using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it using the [Case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) statement. The required columns are created in annotate. This will work if you know how many Goods_id, PriceGroups_id you will have.

```
from django.db.models import Q

aaa = Price.objects.all().prefetch_related('price')

    bbb = Goods.objects.annotate(
        PriceGroups_id_1_price=Case(
            When(id=1, then=aaa.filter(Q(goods__id=1) & Q(pricegroup__id=1)).values_list('price', flat=True)),
            When(id=2, then=aaa.filter(Q(goods__id=2) & Q(pricegroup__id=1)).values_list('price', flat=True)),
        ),
        PriceGroups_id_2_price=Case(
            When(id=1, then=aaa.filter(Q(goods__id=1) & Q(pricegroup__id=2)).values_list('price', flat=True)),
            When(id=2, then=aaa.filter(Q(goods__id=2) & Q(pricegroup__id=2)).values_list('price', flat=True)),
        ),
        PriceGroups_id_3_price=Case(
            When(id=1, then=aaa.filter(Q(goods__id=1) & Q(pricegroup__id=3)).values_list('price', flat=True)),
            When(id=2, then=aaa.filter(Q(goods__id=2) & Q(pricegroup__id=3)).values_list('price', flat=True)),
        ),
    ).values('id', 'PriceGroups_id_1_price', 'PriceGroups_id_2_price', 'PriceGroups_id_3_price')
```

And if you print in a loop:

```
for i in bbb:
    print(i)
```

Output

```
{'id': 1, 'PriceGroups_id_1_price': Decimal('20'), 'PriceGroups_id_2_price': Decimal('25'), 'PriceGroups_id_3_price': Decimal('30')}
{'id': 2, 'PriceGroups_id_1_price': Decimal('40'), 'PriceGroups_id_2_price': Decimal('45'), 'PriceGroups_id_3_price': Decimal('50')}
```